# tensorflow 学習できない

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflowの画像認識について質問をします．

独自のデータセットを用いて，1つの物体を認識するためのモデルファイルを出力するプログラムを参考URLから拝見しました．
参考URLからソースコードを参考に，プログラムを制作し実行しました(model.py)．
何もエラーはなく実行することができたのですが，学習データの訓練がされておらず，データに対する精度が表示されませんでした．
もしこのような問題を解決する方法をご存じでしたら、ご教授をお願いします．
よろしくお願いいたします．

**・参考URL**
http://qiita.com/summer4an/items/db0124eee8103c1d3b85 (ソースコード)

**・環境**
win10
opencv 3.1.0 
python 3.6.0
Anaconda 4.3.1(64bit)
tensorflow '0.12.0-rc1'

**・実行結果**
[image: 実行結果]

**・フォルダ構成**
C:/Ana3/envs/tensorflow (tensorflow，opencv インストールフォルダ)
    ├ tutorial/
    │     ├ gakusyuu.jpg(学習用画像ファイル)
    │     ├ test.jpg(評価用画像ファイル)
    │     ├ train.txt(学習用画像ファイルのパスとラベル)
    │     ├ test.txt(評価用画像ファイルのパスとラベル)
    │        └ model.py(学習するためのソースコード)
    └ output/
　└model.ckpt(最終的なモデル)

**・テキストファイル(一部)**
 train.txt(パス　ラベル)
 C:/Ana3//tutorial/gakusyuu0.jpg 0
 C:/Ana3//tutorial/gakusyuu1.jpg 0

test.txt(パス　ラベル)
 C:/Ana3//tutorial/test0.jpg 0
 C:/Ana3//tutorial/test1.jpg 0

**・ソースコード(model.py)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#参考URL: http://qiita.com/summer4an/items/db0124eee8103c1d3b85
#参考URL:http://kivantium.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/11/18/233834

import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.python.platform

NUM_CLASSES = 1 #一つの物体だけ認識するので分類は1
IMAGE_SIZE = 28
IMAGE_PIXELS = IMAGE_SIZE*IMAGE_SIZE*3

flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_string('train', 'train.txt', 'File name of train data')
flags.DEFINE_string('test', 'test.txt', 'File name of train data')
flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', 'C:\Ana3\\tutorial', 'Directory to put the training data.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 100, 'Number of steps to run trainer.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 10, 'Batch size'
                     'Must divide evenly into the dataset sizes.')
flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 1e-4, 'Initial learning rate.')

def inference(images_placeholder, keep_prob):
    """ 予測モデルを作成する関数

    引数:
      images_placeholder: 画像のplaceholder
      keep_prob: dropout率のplace_holder

    返り値:
      y_conv: 各クラスの確率(のようなもの)
    """
    # 重みを標準偏差0.1の正規分布で初期化
    def weight_variable(shape):
      initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
      return tf.Variable(initial)

    # バイアスを標準偏差0.1の正規分布で初期化
    def bias_variable(shape):
      initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
      return tf.Variable(initial)

    # 畳み込み層の作成
    def conv2d(x, W):
      return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    # プーリング層の作成
    def max_pool_2x2(x):
      return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                            strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    # 入力を28x28x3に変形
    x_image = tf.reshape(images_placeholder, [-1, 28, 28, 3])

    # 畳み込み層1の作成
    with tf.name_scope('conv1') as scope:
        W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 3, 32])
        b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
        h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

    # プーリング層1の作成
    with tf.name_scope('pool1') as scope:
        h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    # 畳み込み層2の作成
    with tf.name_scope('conv2') as scope:
        W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
        b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
        h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

    # プーリング層2の作成
    with tf.name_scope('pool2') as scope:
        h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    # 全結合層1の作成
    with tf.name_scope('fc1') as scope:
        W_fc1 = weight_variable([7*7*64, 1024])
        b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
        h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
        h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
        # dropoutの設定
        h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    # 全結合層2の作成
    with tf.name_scope('fc2') as scope:
        W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, NUM_CLASSES])
        b_fc2 = bias_variable([NUM_CLASSES])

    # ソフトマックス関数による正規化
    with tf.name_scope('softmax') as scope:
        y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

    # 各ラベルの確率のようなものを返す
    return y_conv

def loss(logits, labels):
    """ lossを計算する関数

    引数:
      logits: ロジットのtensor, float - [batch_size, NUM_CLASSES]
      labels: ラベルのtensor, int32 - [batch_size, NUM_CLASSES]

    返り値:
      cross_entropy: 交差エントロピーのtensor, float

    """

    # 交差エントロピーの計算
    #cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(labels*tf.log(logits)) 異常処理 http://qiita.com/ikki8412/items/3846697668fc37e3b7e0
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(labels*tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(logits,1e-10,1.0)))
    # TensorBoardで表示するよう指定
    tf.summary.scalar("cross_entropy", cross_entropy)
    return cross_entropy

def training(loss, learning_rate):
    """ 訓練のOpを定義する関数

    引数:
      loss: 損失のtensor, loss()の結果
      learning_rate: 学習係数

    返り値:
      train_step: 訓練のOp

    """

    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
    return train_step

def accuracy(logits, labels):
    """ 正解率(accuracy)を計算する関数

    引数:
      logits: inference()の結果
      labels: ラベルのtensor, int32 - [batch_size, NUM_CLASSES]

    返り値:
      accuracy: 正解率(float)

    """
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
    return accuracy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ファイルを開く
    f = open(FLAGS.train, 'r')
    # データを入れる配列
    train_image = []
    train_label = []
    for line in f:
        # 改行を除いてスペース区切りにする
        line = line.rstrip()
        l = line.split()
        # データを読み込んで28x28に縮小

        print
        "aaaaa line[%s] %s %s"%(line,l[0],l[1])

        img = cv2.imread(l[0])
        img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))
        # 一列にした後、0-1のfloat値にする
        train_image.append(img.flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.0)
        # ラベルを1-of-k方式で用意する
        tmp = np.zeros(NUM_CLASSES)
        tmp[int(l[1])] = 1
        train_label.append(tmp)
    # numpy形式に変換
    train_image = np.asarray(train_image)
    train_label = np.asarray(train_label)
    f.close()

    f = open(FLAGS.test, 'r')
    test_image = []
    test_label = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        l = line.split()
        img = cv2.imread(l[0])
        img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))

        print
        "aaaaa2 line[%s] %s %s"%(line,l[0],l[1])

        test_image.append(img.flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.0)
        tmp = np.zeros(NUM_CLASSES)
        tmp[int(l[1])] = 1
        test_label.append(tmp)
    test_image = np.asarray(test_image)
    test_label = np.asarray(test_label)
    f.close()

    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        # 画像を入れる仮のTensor
        images_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(None, IMAGE_PIXELS))
        # ラベルを入れる仮のTensor
        labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(None, NUM_CLASSES))
        # dropout率を入れる仮のTensor
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")

        # inference()を呼び出してモデルを作る
        logits = inference(images_placeholder, keep_prob)
        # loss()を呼び出して損失を計算
        loss_value = loss(logits, labels_placeholder)
        # training()を呼び出して訓練
        train_op = training(loss_value, FLAGS.learning_rate)
        # 精度の計算
        acc = accuracy(logits, labels_placeholder)

        # 保存の準備
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        # Sessionの作成
        sess = tf.Session()
        # 変数の初期化
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        # TensorBoardで表示する値の設定
        summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, sess.graph)

        # 訓練の実行
        for step in range(FLAGS.max_steps):
            for i in range(len(train_image)//FLAGS.batch_size):
                # batch_size分の画像に対して訓練の実行
                batch = FLAGS.batch_size*i
                # feed_dictでplaceholderに入れるデータを指定する
                sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={
                  images_placeholder: train_image[batch:batch+FLAGS.batch_size],
                  labels_placeholder: train_label[batch:batch+FLAGS.batch_size],
                  keep_prob: 0.5})

            # 1 step終わるたびに精度を計算する
            train_accuracy = sess.run(acc, feed_dict={
                images_placeholder: train_image,
                labels_placeholder: train_label,
                keep_prob: 1.0})
            print
            "step %d, training accuracy %g"%(step, train_accuracy)

            # 1 step終わるたびにTensorBoardに表示する値を追加する
            summary_str = sess.run(summary_op, feed_dict={
                images_placeholder: train_image,
                labels_placeholder: train_label,
                keep_prob: 1.0})
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)

    # 訓練が終了したらテストデータに対する精度を表示
    print
    "test accuracy %g"%sess.run(acc, feed_dict={
        images_placeholder: test_image,
        labels_placeholder: test_label,
        keep_prob: 1.0})

    # 最終的なモデルを保存
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "C:\Ana3\\tutorial\output\model.ckpt")
```

Comment: 「学習が行われていない」というのは「出力がない」ということでよろしいでしょうか？python3.x系を使われているようなのでprint文はprint("hoge %d"%val)の形(()が必要)である必要があると思います。print直後の改行も不要です。またtensorboard用の指定をおこなっているのであるならばtensorboardの設定を見た方が収束具合がわかりやすいかと思います。

Comment: @H.H　さん，print文がpython2.0系のままにしていたのが原因でした．おかげで解決することができました．ありがとうございます．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(コメント文より)

python3.x系を使われているような‌​のでprint文はprint("hoge %d"%val)の形(()が必要)である必要があると思います。
print直後の改行も不要です。

またtensorboard‌​用の指定をおこなっているのであるならばt‌​ensorboardの設定を見た方が収束‌​具合がわかりやすいかと思います。